# XAML access user directory

Tags: c#, nlog

I want Nlog to save log file in user directory, so I need to have that line in Nlog's config file:

```
<target name="logfile" xsi:type="File" fileName="log.txt" />
```

I'm looking for something like that...

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile);
```

...but in XAML.

Comment: The NLog config file isn't XAML. It is a plain XML file.

Comment: Thanks. That should do the job. But for further research I would still like to know how to do this in XAML.